# Read relative path (outside class path) using main and test classes

Tags: java

I have a project with this structure

```
data_folder/
myProject
    module1
        main/java
        test/java
        pom.xml
    module2
    ...
pom.xml
```

I would like to access `data_folder` using both test and main classes.

In test classes, it's possible using

```
new File("data_folder/myfile.txt")
```

But in main classes, it's only possible using

```
new File("../data_folder/myfile.txt")
```

These files have to be outside the class path because they're editable. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: why not have a fixed location for myfile.txt and use that location in your code by specifying full path?

Comment: If they are editable, then they are outside of your project. I suggest you to have a variable like `inputDirectory` and place your editable files in it. For test purpose, this `inputDirectory` can be a temp dir located in `/tmp`.

Comment: What environment are we in? Are we running from an IDE or from a shell?

Comment: @svasa the full path is not an option. data_folder is distributed with the git repo on the root folder myProject.

Comment: @rghome I would like to find a solution that works for both.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can set a run configuration that specifies the current directory to run from. If running from the shell,  you can just cd to the right directory. Set CLASSPATH to say where your .class files are.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to do this would be to pass in the full location of data_folder as a parameter when you start your programs/tests:

`-DFILES_LOCATION=/somelocation/data_folder`

Then access and create files like this:

`String root_dir = System.getProperty("FILES_LOCATION");`
`File myFile = new File(rootDir+File.separator+"myfile.txt")`

Then it doesn't matter if it's a relative path or not - you just point to where the input/data files are.